# Does area51 auto recalc rep now?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I just noticed that my rep on area51 are changed and synced with /reputation tab, and I didn't request for recalc.

So, is that mean area51 now auto recalc? or just another global recalc happened? or someone just recalc my rep somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. At least, not for me it didn't... My rep is still quite a bit higher than it should be, due to quite some deleted proposals.

Comment: I see, may be only me then.